# How to make seo friendly form_key whishlist link

Tags: magento-1.9, url-rewrite, seo, form-key

```
https://www.websitename.in/wishlist/index/addd/product/715/form_key/1LEJOC1edAL6N0Wi/
```

Seo person asked me to make these links seo friendly . Is there any way in which this can be achieved.

[image: link]

Comment: you should avoid wishlist  Url at seo.Bcoz `form_key` always be dynamic

Comment: means i can not change this url

Comment: tell the seo person it's not a good idea, and should add `rel="nofollow"` to the links instead.

Comment: Thanku @subroutines I surely ask them to do this .If there is no harm on seo ranking.

Answer (score 0):

Exclude link paths by robots.txt